How would a native Swiss say "Is the car still available?"
I am suspecting that a car dealership in Switzerland was not being honest when they told me the car was sold as soon as it was put up for sale. My suspicion is that they don't want to deal with a foreign buyer.
Help me test this theory - how would a local Swiss (or a German) say something like "Is the car still available for sale?"
Google translate says "Hallo, steht das Auto noch zum Verkauf?" but I would like to be sure it sounds natural to them, for obvious reasons :)
Regular German (non-Swiss) phrase would be OK, too.

If you are going to call, you'd have to speak Swiss-German to not get marked as foreigner (allegedly). Good luck with that ;)
And if you are going to write an email, you should stick to standard German (except substitute each ß with ss). Swiss German has no official written form, we write things in german. Some people write in Swiss German with close Friends, but it can be very messy, and everyone has their own style (since there are no rules).
Your own translation result seems fine.

I read" Grüezi " is a formal greeting...

Yes, but that's swiss german. I wouldn't write Grüezi in an email if I'll proceed with German. I would use "Guten Tag" instead.
Guten Tag,  
Ich interessiere mich für Ihren [insert car name]. Steht der noch zum Verkauf?

Mit freundlichen Grüssen
Ivan


Many thanks! By the way, I was right - when asking in German, the reply is "the car is still available"

I think the most natural and probably most used (Standard German) option for »Is the car still available?« would be:

Ist das Auto noch zu haben?



Google translate says "Hallo, steht das Auto noch zum Verkauf?"

First off, I'm not Swiss, but the answer to this question wouldn't change between Swiss and other varieties of the German language anyway.
Yes, the sentence of Google translate is completely OK and idiomatic. The only point to "critisize" is the "Hallo" at the begin. Your original sentence

"Is the car still available for sale?"

doesn't contain any addressing and hence the "Hallo" is not rightfully part of the translation. Nevertheless, if I were to start a talk, I would first greet my counterpart and it would quite likely be by "hallo" or some variation of it. So, it is not wrong, it is also quite the way natives would talk - it is just not part of the translation of the question sentence.
A verbatim translation would be:

Stands the car still for sale?

because "zum Verkauf stehen" ("stehen" = to stand, "zum Verkauf" = for sale). Notice that "stehen", especially in phrases, has a much broader meaning in German than "to stand" has in English, e.g. "zur Verfügung stehen" = to be available, "geschrieben stehen" = to be written, and so on. In the same way: "zum Verkauf stehen" = to be up for sale.

Thanks so much for the answer!
if "Hallo" is not part of the question, what would you write when e.g. starting an email or posting a question using an online form? I read" Grüezi " is a formal greeting...

"Grüezi" is short for "Ich grüße Sie", which is indeed formal (and out of use today), but "Grüezi" is not considered formal at all. As I wrote "Hallo" (or "Guten Tag") is a proper way of starting an e-mail. I was just mentioning that the translation of "is the car available..." is not "Hallo, steht das Auto...", but "Steht das Auto...".
